# How to I make a code Loop 3 times in Python as well as having a while loop around it

Tags: python

Very limited on using python and totally stuck, I've managed to get a while loop running on the code below so that the user can keep entering a code until they put in the correct one.

What I'm now looking to do is add a for loop so that it only asks the user to enter the code (4 wrong digits) 3 times and then locks them out. At the same time it needs a while loop to ensure if the user puts more than or less than 4 digits it continually runs and doesn't lock them out.

I just cant get the for loop and while loop working at the same time and don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
user = ("1234")

valid = False

while not valid:

   #for i in range (3):  

        user = input("Hello, welcome! Please enter a four digit passcode to open the safe: ")
        user = user.upper()          

        if user == ("1234") :
            print("You have cracked the code, well done")
            valid = True
            break

        if user != ("1234") :
            print ("that is incorrect, please try again")
            valid = False



        elif len(user) > 4:
            print ("That is incorrect, please try again")
            valid = False

        elif len(user) < 4:
            print ("That is incorrect, please try again")
            valid = False
        else:
            print ("You have been locked out!! Alarm!!!!!!")
```

Comment: Does it need to be a for loop for some assignment or would adding a simple counter and `while not valid and counter < 3` work?

Comment: It does say a for loop and while loop. It also says a case statement which I have no idea what that is :(

Answer (score 2):

```
user = ("1234")

counter = 0

while counter < 3:

    user = input("Hello, welcome! Please enter a four digit passcode to open the safe: ")
    user = user.upper()         

    if len(user) != 4:
        print("I said 4 digits!")
        continue

    if user == ("1234") :
        print("You have cracked the code, well done")
        break

    print ("that is incorrect, please try again")
        counter += 1

if counter == 3:
    print ("You have been locked out!! Alarm!!!!!!")
else:
    print ("Everything is fine.")
```

Comment: Thank you! Great help :)

Answer (score 0):

I adapted your code a little bit and added a counter variable

```
user = ("1234")

valid = False
counter = 0

while not valid:

        user = input("Hello, welcome! Please enter a four digit passcode to open the safe: ")
        user = user.upper()          

        if user == ("1234") :
            print("You have cracked the code, well done")
            valid = True
            break

        elif len(user) != 4:
            print ("That is incorrect, please try again")

        else:
            print ("that is incorrect, please try again")
            counter = counter + 1

            if counter == 3:
                print ("You have been locked out!! Alarm!!!!!!")

                #Do stuff to actually abort here...
```

It counts up if there is a wrong answer now

Answer (score 0):

the inner loop is just for valid input:

```
user = '1234'
locked = False
miss_cnt = 0
while True:
    while True:
        ans = raw_input('User -> ')
        if len(ans) == 4 and ans.isdigit():
            break

    if ans != user:
        miss_cnt += 1
        if miss_cnt >= 3:
            locked = True
            break
    else:
        break
```

I left out the prints for clarity of flow

Comment: Thank you!! That's a great help!

Answer (score 0):

The following code should work for you.

```
answer = "1234"

valid = False
count = 0

while not valid and count < 3:
    user = input("Hello, welcome! Please enter a four digit passcode to open the safe: ")
    user = user.upper()          

    if user == answer:
        print("You have cracked the code, well done")
        valid = True

    elif count < 2:
        print ("that is incorrect, please try again")

    else:
        print ("You have been locked out")

    count += 1
```

I took the `()` off of the strings because that would make them sets so the if statement would never be true, because sets don't equal string inputs.